# Build app cordova IOS no phonegap build

Tags: ios, apache-cordova, phonegap-buillder

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não estou conseguindo buildar um app simples cordova para IOS, wp8 e android builda certinho, alguem ja passou por esse problema?
Ja procurei em varios lugares nao achei nenhuma solução.
Os arquivos .p12 e .mobileprovision foram gerados conforme o 
[link](http://appfurnace.com/2015/01/how-do-i-make-a-p12-file/)

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi conflito entre certificados, apagamos todos os certificados no Keychain e refizemos o procedimento de geração dos arquivos .p12 e .mobileprovision, deu certo!